# how to delete row from tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, tableview

I tried a lot but can't kindly help me out of from this situation

```
//
//  TableViewController.m
//  jsonplaceholder
//
//  Created by manikandan on 19/04/16.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 manikandan. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()
<NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{
    NSString *string;
    NSURL *url;
    NSURLRequest *request;
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    NSMutableData *receivedata;

    NSString *imgstring;
    NSURL *imgurl;

    NSMutableData *imgreceivedata;

       NSMutableArray *dictarry;
     NSMutableArray *dictarry1;
     NSMutableArray *dictarry2;
     NSMutableArray *deldictarray;
     NSMutableArray *deldictarray1;
     NSMutableArray *deldictarray2;

    NSMutableDictionary *dict;
    int a;
}

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

        [super viewDidLoad];
        string =@"http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
        request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
        connection =[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        receivedata =[NSMutableData data];
        NSLog(@"hai");
       imgstring = @"http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-uhWTslN7wO8/UdXSIswnW4I/AAAAAAAACWo/Y10XXAfoGI4/s575/AJITH-OPTIMIZATION+(10).jpg";
        imgurl =[NSURL URLWithString:imgstring];
        imgreceivedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgurl];

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedata setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [receivedata appendData:data];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedata options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",dict);
    dictarry =[dict valueForKey:@"id"];
    dictarry1 =[dict valueForKey:@"title"];
    dictarry2 =[dict valueForKey:@"body"];
    a=[dictarry count];
    NSLog(@"%d",a);
    NSLog(@"%@",dictarry);
    NSLog(@"%@",dictarry1);
    NSLog(@"%@",dictarry2);
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return a;

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *Cellid=@"Cell";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellid forIndexPath:indexPath];


   cell.lbltitle.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]];
    cell.lblsubtitle .text=[dictarry1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lbldescription.text=[dictarry2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imgview .image=[UIImage imageWithData:imgreceivedata];

    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detail =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];

    detail.passstring1=[[dictarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue] ;
    detail.passstring2=[dictarry1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detail.passstring3=[dictarry2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detail.passstring4=imgreceivedata;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail  animated:YES];

}



- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

  /* code problem here i can't  resolve it kindly help me.`enter code here`*/
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

 // I  just create 3 array to transfer value
```

> ```
>     a=a-1;
> ```

```
    deldictarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:dictarry];
    deldictarray1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:dictarry1];
    deldictarray2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:dictarry2];

    [deldictarray1 removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [deldictarray2 removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row ]];
    [deldictarray removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

   [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   dictarry=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:deldictarray];
   dictarry1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:deldictarray1];
    dictarry2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:deldictarray2];
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[dictarry count]);
                 [self.tableView reloadData];



    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}


@end
```

//here i attached my log report also

> 2016-04-21 10:51:27.046 jsonplaceholder[469:60b] -[**NSArrayI
>   removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x8c3c650 2016-04-21 10:51:27.137 jsonplaceholder[469:60b] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI
>   removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x8c3c650'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x017f11e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x015708e5 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0188e243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275  3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x017e150b ___forwarding_** + 1019
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x017e10ee
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14    5   jsonplaceholder                     0x00003d02 -[TableViewController
>   tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:] + 178    6   UIKit
>   0x0032a6a3 -[UITableView animateDeletionOfRowWithCell:] + 107     7
>   UIKit                               0x004b3595 -[UITableViewCell
>   _swipeDeleteButtonPushed] + 70    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01582880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77  9 
>   UIKit                               0x002323b9 -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108   10  UIKit
>   0x00232345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] +
>   61    11  UIKit                               0x00333bd1 -[UIControl
>   sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66     12  UIKit
>   0x00333fc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577    13 
>   UIKit                               0x00333243 -[UIControl
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641    14  UIKit
>   0x005c82e3 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 7166  15  UIKit
>   0x00271a5a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291  16  UIKit
>   0x00272971 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1021  17  UIKit
>   0x002445f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242  18  UIKit
>   0x0022e353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455     19  CoreFoundation 
>   0x0177a77f **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 15  20  CoreFoundation                      0x0177a10b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235  21  CoreFoundation                      0x017971ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910     22  CoreFoundation
>   0x017969d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467     23  CoreFoundation
>   0x017967eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   24  GraphicsServices
>   0x037e55ee GSEventRunModal + 192  25  GraphicsServices
>   0x037e542b GSEventRun + 104   26  UIKit
>   0x00230f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225   27  jsonplaceholder
>   0x0000411d main + 141     28  libdyld.dylib
>   0x01e3870d start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: I never see you decrement the integer you're using to return numberOfRowsInSection. Ideally you wouldn't maintain the number of items as a separate int (should probably be NSInteger anyway) but count the items in your data source. e.g. [dictarry count] (also dictarry is not an ideal name for an array). If that isn't an option you need to decrement a after you remove the object with a--;

Comment: after i changed still i have that problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use the assignments as follows:

```
dictarry = [[dict valueForKey:@"id"] mutableCopy];
dictarry1 = [[dict valueForKey:@"title"] mutableCopy];
dictarry2 = [[dict valueForKey:@"body"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: but still i have that problem

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Objective-C is an object oriented language. Use a custom class instead of three arrays as data source.

To solve your issue forget that `a` variable and return always the number of items in `dictarry`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return dictarry.count;
}
```

And delete the line to reload the table view in `commitEditingStyle` because `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` rearranges the table view automatically.

**Edit**

Your crash log reveals that the three data source arrays are immutable. Although they are declared as `NSMutabeArray`, the KVC method `valueForKey:` returns an immutable array. Change these three lines:

```
dictarry = [[dict valueForKey:@"id"] mutableCopy];
dictarry1 = [[dict valueForKey:@"title"] mutableCopy];
dictarry2 = [[dict valueForKey:@"body"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: still i have that problem

Comment: @tamilan manikandan - you are managing data in wrong manner, your data has to be in dictionary and dictionary in mutable array. why keeping separate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the value you are passing to your mutable array, that array is not mutable. Hence, removeObjectAtIndex: is failing.

Please add the values as:

```
dictarry  = [[dict valueForKey:@"id"] mutableCopy];
```

Thus the array becomes mutable.

Comment: Neither `beginUpdates` nor `endUpdates` nor `reloadData` is needed. The method `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` implicitly reloads the table view and `begin/endUpdates` is only required for multiple `insert/delete/move` operations.

Comment: He was using deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: that signifies multiple, so thats i just suggested. But, good you pointed out. But my main answer of mutablecopy was correct, as desired. @vadian Thanks !

Comment: No, multiple means several *different* operations like an `insert...` followed by a `delete...` line